# Discord.js message.react fails when adding specific unicode emotes

Tags: node.js, emoji, discord.js

Yesterday I started coding a bot using the guide from discord.js. [The core](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/tree/master/code_samples/command-handling/file-setup) is just with what you finish the Command Handler part with.
I was working on a voting command, where the bot would react with Unicode symbols like :one: :two: :three:.
This is where I encounter my problem. Using:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'testing',
description: 'creates a reaction',
aliases: ['test'],
cooldown: 1,
execute(message, args) {
    if (!args.length) {
        message.react(':one:');
    }      
}
```

};
Gives me a `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji`

I spend some time trying different emotes like  and they are working as expected. Using the emote ID (422515569623957504) does not work as well for me.

Is this a mistake on my side or a bug?

Comment: Also have a look at [unicode problems with emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339653/how-do-i-send-number-boxes-emojis-1️⃣/57339887)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Discord.js to react a message with a emoji you need to write the emoji (with  or , full list [here](https://getemoji.com/)) or with a [Emoji](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji).
To react with numbers you can use this:

```
0⃣ 1⃣ 2⃣ 3⃣ 4⃣ 5⃣ 6⃣ 7⃣ 8⃣ 9⃣
```

Just copy the number you need and you're all set.
To react a message with a custom emoji, you need to do something like this:

```
message.react(message.guild.emojis.get('123456789012345678'))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Note: Bots can use emojis from all servers (like Nitro). `client.emojis` returns a Collection of all emojis the bot can use, `client.emojis.get('id')` to get the emoji from another server.

Comment: I worked yesterday with another programmer from of my servers. The first thing you propose does not work. But I will try the second one. We found another way to do it: For :one: it is possible to use '\u0031\u20E3'. For some reason, the Unicode for this emoji does not work properly. If you ask discord to show the escaped version it will just give you :one: as a result. Thanks anyway for the suggestion, I will upvote it once I tested it

Comment: As of 2019, this indeed works. An extremely easy error to make is to leave out a space when copy-pasting these, as they have strange overlapping. Failure to do so will result in `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji`