# How do I send number boxes emojis (1️⃣)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, emoji

How do I send them? If I try this: msg.react('1️⃣') it replies with an error telling me that this is an unknown emoji. What shall I do?

```
client.on("message", async msg => {
   if (command === 'vote') {
       msg.channel.send('response')
           .then(m => m.react('1️⃣')
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add more information, we have no code here, no technologies (also add tags). What is `msg` ?? What is his `react()` function ?

Comment: @Arthur `react()` is a type of interaction on Discord messages, the tags used should be enough.

Comment: Based on the Discord doc, your code should works fine https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#unicode-emojis

Comment: Are you sure they are both the same ? Between `:one: 1️⃣` (try to put this on discord) because they look like different for me. In order to use `.react()` you have to be sure you use the exact same emojy

Comment: Sorry but why are you missing a `)` after the .then line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [discordjs.guide ( the opensource guide maintained by the discord.js community).](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples.html#emoji-characters)

Do something like ( or just copy and paste the numbers ):

> ```
> // emojiCharacters.js
> module.exports = {
>     a: '', b: '', c: '', d: '',
>     e: '', f: '', g: '', h: '',
>     i: '', j: '', k: '', l: '',
>     m: '', n: '', o: '', p: '',
>     q: '', r: '', s: '', t: '',
>     u: '', v: '', w: '', x: '',
>     y: '', z: '', 0: '0⃣', 1: '1⃣',
>     2: '2⃣', 3: '3⃣', 4: '4⃣', 5: '5⃣',
>     6: '6⃣', 7: '7⃣', 8: '8⃣', 9: '9⃣',
>     10: '', '#': '#⃣', '*': '*⃣',
>     '!': '❗', '?': '❓',
> };
> ```

Then you could do:

> ```
> // index.js
> const emojiCharacters = require('./emojiCharacters');
> console.log(emojiCharacters.a); // 
> console.log(emojiCharacters[10]); // 
> console.log(emojiCharacters['!']); // ❗
> ```

Comment: *or copy and paste* ... thats what the OP did?

Comment: When I paste OP's emoji directly into Discord, it even shows up as weiered one: ![see here](https://plasmasharex.page.link/Jvi6)

Comment: Yep, `:one:` and `1️⃣` are different for Discord

Comment: `1⃣` will turn into `:one:`

Comment: @TheDeveloper This Questions still seems to be unresolved, could you please mark a Answer as accepted, or self answer if you have found the Solution?

Answer (score 1):

You used 1️⃣ instead of 1⃣. Yes, they are different.

The first one has three unicode codepoints:

49 - number 1

**65039 - ["variation selector 16"¹](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0f/index.htm)**

8419 - ["combining enclosing keycap"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e3/index.htm) (the background)

The second version doesn't have that code point in the middle (49, 8419) and that seems to work.

---

¹ I found the [following quote](https://emojipedia.org/variation-selector-16/) describing its meaning:

> An invisible codepoint which specifies that the preceding character should be displayed with emoji presentation. Only required if the preceding character defaults to text presentation.

It's fun though that DiscordJS doesn't ignore it.

Comment: Oh... well that's something. How do I type for example an equivalent to 2️⃣ then?

Comment: To be honest I tried looking them up in a unicode database, and I ended up at the same entry ... I'll keep trying ...

Comment: @theDeveloper finally found a hidden codepoint that causes problems with discordJS. I'll dig into discordJS source and will file a bug there.

Comment: I [filed a bug report on Github](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/1047)