# DiscordJS - React with a :one:

Tags: discord, discord.js

I cannot figure out how to react with a :one: Emoji with DiscordJs.

Usually placing an escape \ infront of the Emoji would give you the id of the Emoji, but with \ [image: this] happens

Reacting with :one: or one or the discord link doesn't work either.

(https://ptb.discordapp.com/assets/d10eead5823437c08b5287cf93bd5223.svg => 10eead5823437c08b5287cf93bd5223)

When using the symbol that @Nathn suggested, it still throws an error:
[image]

### My Solution

The solution that I used was to pick "E0.6 keycap 1" from an Emoji Picker instead of "keycap 1". I recommend doing it the way @a2br suggested with creating your own emote - that way it will stay consistent across devices.

Also if you are going to put those emojis into fixed width text containers you wont need to worry about the "keycap 1" actually being 3 characters (1 + glueChar + keyCap) and rendering it as 3 characters on some devices and other devices rendering it as 1.5 width for whatever reason.

Comment: You don't need the emoji ID, you can just do `message.react("1️")`

Comment: It can be confusing beacause 1 and 1️ are similar symbols, but `message.react("1")` will return an error and `message.react("1️")` will react with the :one: emoji

Comment: @Nathn I dont see the difference between the 2 ones that you sent, but I will copy paste then. Put your comment into an answer and if it works i'll give you the checkmark. (Also tell me please where i can get those symbols from)

Comment: @Nathn It didn't seem to work. Instead of `Unkown Emoji` I now got `Emoji_Type` as an error

Comment: Try copy-pasting 1️⃣, 2️⃣, 3️⃣, 4️⃣, 5️⃣, 6️⃣, 7️⃣, 8️⃣, 9️⃣, or  into your code and see if it works.

Comment: @Lioness100 thank you I have figured it out, I used the "keycap 1" emoji but needed to use "E0.6 keycap 1" for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I last used Discord.js, but I remember very well this specific issue; I don't know why, but Discord bots do not support the number emojis.

I think you could avoid that problem by creating a custom emoji in a server your bot is in (and using `<:one:000000000000000000>` with whatever your emoji ID is), the only difference is that it'll render the same on mobile platforms, where emojis should usually be rendered natively.

Edit: Oh, I didn't read the whole question. The solution above was written for text messages, not reactions. So, for reactions, it'd be `message.react("000000000000000000")`. There's probably a better solution though, also here is what's been [answered in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231913/13230118).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Unicode short names like `:one:` or you can use the escaped versions/Unicode characters like `1️⃣` in the `message.react()`.

Examples:

```js
//Unicode shortnames
message.react(':one:')


//Unicode character
message.react('1️⃣')
```

Note that both the short name or Unicode characters need to be in a string.

Comment: > Reacting with :one: or one or the discord link doesn't work either. < 3rd line in my question :D
You can try it out it doesn't work

Comment: Turns out there is no Unicode character for :one:

Sending \:one: in a channel doesn't work.

Try using the unicode characters from lioness100 in a previous reply.